# Mongo won't allow me to backup my databases

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a new pc and am trying to migrate over my mongodbs.

On my old pc I'm using 3.2.10 and 3.4 on the new one.

I thought the best method would be to simple back and restore on the new pc, however when I try and use the command  'mongodump'

I just get the error message:

```
2017-01-14T16:29:47.416+0900 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: mongodump is not defined :
@(shell):1:1
```

Comment: How is this question related to Python?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of code where you try to call mongodump?

Answer (score 2):

you're running `mongodump` inside `mongo` but it's part of mongo commands! so exit `mongo-cli` and run it in bash!

Comment: Oh yeah that was silly of me, thanks ! Bonus question: Now i get `Failed: error dumping metadata: error creating directory for metadata file dump\margin_calls: mkdir dump: Access is denied.`

Comment: use `sudo` or change the export directory to where you've permissions!

Comment: I use windows, could you translate that to windows talk ?

Comment: Oh, okay:) use [`-o <path>`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--out) and put the desired location in `<path>`. Also you can create `dump` folder!

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't get it to work :( . When I use command `mongodump -o C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin ` it gives error: `2017-01-14T17:17:42.510+0900    positional arguments not allowed: [Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin]`

Comment: You've and space in your `-o` param! use quotation around it! Also change the path to somewhere better! create an empty folder for example!